# Slow database performance after mysqldump backup

Tags: mysql-5.6, mysqldump, percona

we are using mysql 5.6-91 (percona) as the backend database. Everyday morning mysqldump is used to back up the entire database and upload it to s3. The database size is around 70GB. The issue we are facing is after the dump, the performance of the database is extremely slow. The performance is back after restarting the server or sometimes after rebooting the whole instance itself.

System configuration is as follows

32GB Ram
16core CPU
Ubuntu 18
Engine: InnoDB

My.cnf

```
# custom configurations go here
sort_buffer_size = 64M
tmp_table_size = 128M
group_concat_max_len = 8192
query_cache_type = 0
query_cache_size = 0
max_connections = 500
thread_cache_size = 50
open_files_limit = 65535
table_definition_cache = 1024
innodb_log_file_size = 2G
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 23G
log-error = /var/log/mysql/mysql-error.log
log-queries-not-using-indexes = 0
slow-query-log = 0
slow-query-log-file = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 12
```

Comment: Additional DB information request (after mysqldump done and your are SLOW), please. 
OS, Version? 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,  
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE, 
top -b -n 1  for most active apps, 
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
df -h  for Used - Free space by device, 
df -i  for inode info by device, 
free -h  for Used - Free  Mem: and Swap:, 
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,  
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.